# How to stop video slider autoplay, when video playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I used swiper.js slider for video slide.
I want set autoplay , when video playing, swiper autoplay stop.

```
                          var storySwiper = new Swiper(vcat_id + ' .swiper-container',  {
                            slidesPerView: 1,
                            slidesPerGroup: 1,
                            loop: true,
                            autoHeight: false,
                            speed:3000,
                            autoplay: {
                                delay: 3000,
                                disableOnInteraction: false,
                                // waitForTransition: true,
                                // sliderFirstMove:true,
                                pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
                            },
                            navigation: {
                                nextEl: vcat_id + ' .swiper-button-next',
                                prevEl: vcat_id + ' .swiper-button-prev',
                            },
                            breakpoints: {  
                                768: {  
                                        slidesPerView:3,
                                        // spaceBetween: 30,
                                        // autoplay: false,
                                        freemode: false,
                                    }
                            },
                            on: {
                                slideChange: function (ell) {
                                  $('.swiper-slide').each(function () {
                                      var youtubePlayera = $(this).find('iframe').get(0);
                                      if (youtubePlayera) {
                                        youtubePlayera.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
                                      }
                                  });
                                },
                            }
```

Comment: I fixed your code so it's almost readable - perhaps you can fix it so it isn't off the page to the right like that